# why won't RVM (Ruby Version Manager) install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

So my goal is to upgrade Rails from 5.0.6 to the newest version on Windows 10 in order to follow a tutorial that uses it.  If I understand correctly then i need to install RVM in order to upgrade my Rails version. from the RVM site https://rvm.io/rvm/install the first command to install it is:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BD
```

however i get the following error:

```
'gpg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

so my question is, do i need to install the RVM and if so how can i proceed?

if I upgrade to Rails 5.1.5 will the apps i made with my 5.0.6 be backwards compatible and still work on my machine or will they break? I am quite confused as to the issue of upgrading since all the videos and articles on upgrading seem to deal with upgrading individual apps and not the actual Rails software itself.

EDIT 1: added gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

ruby '2.2.6'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'

# Rails defaults
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# learn-rails
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'jquery-rails'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :test do
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
end
```

now rails server wont start wıth error:

```
C:\Sites\learn-rails>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:45:in `full_gem_path': uninitialized constant Bundler::Plugin::API::Source (NameError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:145:in `block in full_require_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `full_require_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:77:in `contains_requirable_file?'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `block in find_in_unresolved'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `find_all'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `find_in_unresolved'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:74:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/plugin/api/source.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:45:in `full_gem_path'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:145:in `block in full_require_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `full_require_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1370:in `add_self_to_load_path'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1283:in `activate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `block in gem'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `synchronize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `gem'
        from C:/Sites/learn-rails/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I am even unsure if `rvm` officially supports windows. Also, `5.0.6` should be fine.

Comment: that is what i thought, but the book i am reading doesnt mention this. how would i go about upgrading on windows then? i can only find information on installing not upgrading. this is strange

Comment: When you refer to upgrading individual apps, I'm assuming you mean the gems in your gemfile? Rails is just one of them, too. If you open up `Gemfile` (NOT `Gemfile.lock`) in your project, you can change the rails version there. Then just run `bundle install`.

Comment: but do i have to do this every time i create a new app or will this be permanent? i am confused as to what ''upgrading Rails'' means then. becasue now when i create an app it uses 5.0.6 by default. how can i get ti to use the newest version without changing the gems in the gemfile individually for each project?

Comment: I would really recommend using docker or some other virtualization tool to run some flavor of linux. You'll be productive and learning instead of strugging to get everything running on an OS that almost nobody actually deploys Rails apps on. Developing on the same OS that you deploy on is a very good idea.

Comment: You specify what gem versions to use in **every project, individually**. But it's mostly done automatically. You can install a new version of rails on top of what you already have, but it won't affect your project unless you change the gemfile. This is completely normal and _a good thing_.

Comment: If you're just learning Rails and are (save for updating) generally happy for now, I wouldn't recommend you try migrating to a different workflow/platform. I especially would not recommend docker as I suspect it would be very alien for you. If you do want to try something else, Ubuntu on Windows is a really handy way to run a linux environment on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to have a Ruby version manager (like RVM) to use Rails, but it is recommended if you're going to be working on multiple projects. Similar to the way Gemfiles keep everyone in sync using the same gems, a Ruby version manager can help ensure that everyone is using the same version of Ruby, too.

The main complication here is that you're using Windows, which RVM **does not support**. You either need to use something like cgywin, or try out Ubuntu on Windows, if you want to use RVM.

Alternatively, you could try a Windows-native tool, like [Uru](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru).

You can continue without using RVM or any other version manager, and upgrading to 5.1 is unlikely to give you any issues if 5.0 was already working smoothly for you.

Comment: ok so i will forget abotu RVM for now then. what is the correct way to upgrade to 5.1 on windows then? do i have to uninstall and reinstall or is there a more direct way to do it?

Comment: Because each Rails project has a Gemfile, different gems (and different versions of gems) can be loaded for one project. You could install a specific version of rails by yourself by running `gem install rails -v 5.1.5`, but even then you would still need to specify in your Gemfile that for your current project you want to use that version. It's as simple as changing the line `gem 'rails', '~>5.0'` (or similar) to `gem 'rails', '~>5.1''`. After this, just run `bundle install` while in your project directory. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: so, if i am specifiying what version of rails i am using in each project individually. what exactly did i install when i installed rails. as i understand there is never any need to upgrade to any version of rails. you just change the Gemfile each time. what do people mean when they talk about upgrading then? i am a bit lost on this now. am i correct in thinking that in the tutorial i will follow (which uses 5.1.2) i can just copy its gem file and then i will be using the latest version of rails?

Comment: Okay, I think we might need to take a step back here. The Gemfile is simply a set of instructions on what to install, but it doesn't do anything itself. Bundler (another ruby gem) reads this file when you run `bundle install`, and for each line, runs the `gem install x -v x.x` command if you don't already have it installed. So if you ran `gem install rails -v 5.1.5` and then added that version to your Gemfile and ran `bundle install`, nothing would really happen.

Comment: This is an upgrade because Rails 5.0 and 5.1 are not the same. For example, 5.1 has support for webpacker natively. But for the most part, you need to enable these features yourself and if you don't nothing will happen.

Comment: I'm assuming you've used something like railsinstaller.org to install Rails, which is fine, but perhaps what is misleading you here. I believe that installer just helps you get setup with all the packages you need to run Ruby and Rails on Windows, but I don't think it's forcing you into a single version. You should be free to make changes.

Comment: i tried updating the gemfile with a later version of rails but now my rails server wont start. see gemfile in edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166107/discussion-between-jon1467-and-owen).